# How copy artifact from teamcity to remote location or folder

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

How to copy the build artifacts from Teamcity to another server?

I tried this command "test/*.msi => \host\test\" in the artifact path, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

[Deployer plugin](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Deployer+plugin) lets TeamCity to upload artifacts to external locations in a number of ways (SMB, FTP, SSH...).